# Rails 'select' form for Delete method of RESTful resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This seems like it should be a simple thing, but I haven't been able to hunt down an illustrative example. Apologies if this question is redundant.

So I have a rails app, and I'm trying to work with a RESTful resource. This is what the route looks like:

*config/routes.rb*

```
resources :articles, only: [:index, :create, :destroy]
```

I want a simple form to delete these in case extras are added or whatever. So here are the form and controller I have so far:

*app/views/articles/_delete.html.haml*

```
%h1 Delete Article
- all_articles = Article.all.sort.reverse.map { |a| [a.name, a.id] }
= form_for @article, method: :delete do |f|
  .form-group
    = f.select :id, options_for_select(all_articles), class: 'form-control'
  = f.submit 'Delete', class: 'btn btn-danger'
```

When I submit this, I get 'No route matches [DELETE] "/articles"'. This is because the route for deletion is articles/:id :

```
DELETE    /articles/:id(.:format)    articles#destroy
```

So my goal is to get the submit button to grab the id, and send off to /articles/:id with the Delete method. If it helps, I'm on Rails 4.1.

I think the real pain point for me here though is not fully understanding how the form helper points to an action or passes data around. If anyone can elucidate I'd be appreciative.

I see that I can define a url on the form_for method, like so:

```
= form_for @article, method: :delete, url: articles_path do |f|
```

But how can I get the id from the form into that url?

Edit: Related: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1769

Comment: You should not write DB call in view file. You can create the object 
`@articles = Article.all.sort.reverse.map { |a| [a.name, a.id] }` and use that in the view file.

Comment: Good point, will do.

Answer (score 2):

Please try

```
= form_for @article, method: :delete, url: articles_path(@article) do |f|
```

And the `url` can be omitted. You may try like this

```
= form_for @article, method: :delete do |f|
```

Thanks to @unused

Comment: that's right, the route is for a single ressource. I'd assume you can omit the url.

Comment: Does @article need to be defined at all ahead of time? I'm trying this but it's still trying to route to /articles.

Comment: Its the same `@article` you're making the `form_for`.

Comment: Thanks @unused for pointing that out and being of so much use. ;)

Comment: So with the url omitted version, isn't that the same thing I started with? Any idea why I'm routing to the wrong place?